# Functional tests in Symfony: how can I get matching to span on several lines?

Tags: php, json, web-services, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

I am building some functional tests for a json api in Symfony.

Using the `sfTestFunctional` object to test my result, I would try to validate the following response:

```
{
    "result": true,
    "content": [
           "one",
           "two"
    ]
}
```

with something like:

```
$browser = new sfTestFunctional(new sfBrowser());

$browser->
    get('/hi')->
    with('response')->
    begin()->
    isStatusCode(200)->
    matches('/result\"\: true/')->
    matches('/one.*two/m')->
end()
```

Now This is what I get:

```
ok 1 - status code is 200
ok 2 - response content matches regex /result\\: true/"
not ok 3 - response content matches regex /one.*two/m
```

Surely, I am doing something wrong. Any hint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex fails.

You should use the [flag `s` for *dotall* (PCRE_DOTALL)](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) which *includes newlines*.

> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded.

So:

```
$browser->
    get('/hi')->
    with('response')->
    begin()->
    isStatusCode(200)->
    matches('/result\"\: true/')->
    matches('/one.*two/sm')->
end()
```

Otherwise you can make two differents tests:

```
$browser->
    get('/hi')->
    with('response')->
    begin()->
    isStatusCode(200)->
    matches('/result\"\: true/')->
    matches('/\"one\"')->
    matches('/\"two\"')->
end()
```

Comment: yes, this is it ! I had to take out the m, but now I can match the newlines. Thanks @jOk !

Comment: So, IO get the match with: matches('/one.*two/s')->